# How to choose ranges to analyse in a given population?

Tags: data-science, data-analysis

I want to analyse weight of elderly population. What is the right way to choose ranges in age to divide this population into? ie. how to choose between ranges of 61-70,71-80 etc or 61-65,66-70 etc?

Is there a right way at all? Or is it up to researcher, taking into account what is analysed? I.e. I know that in case of elderly range 61-80, 81-100 would be too broad, and rages per 1 year too thin. But, can it be objectively defined, 5 or 10 years, is better?

I would be really thankful for your help and perspective!